# Nodejs https not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making an api request to facebook using this:

```
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', config.FACEBOOK_SECRET).update(access_token).digest('hex');
    console.log('hash = ' + hash);
var options = { //start of options
    hostname: 'graph.facebook.com',
    port: 443,
    //path: '/oauth/?appsecret_proof='+hash+'&access_token='+at,
    path: '/v2.6/me?fields=id,email,name&access_token=' + req.body.access_token + '&appsecret_proof=' + hash,
    method: 'GET'
}; //end of options



var fbResponse = [];

var req = https.request(options, (response) => {
      console.log('statusCode: ', response.statusCode);
      console.log('headers: ', response.headers);

      response.on('data', (d) => {
          console.log(d)
         fbResponse.push(d);
      });

      response.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response. ');

        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            r: fbResponse
        }));
        return;

        })
    });


    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e);
       res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            r: 'error'
        }));
        return;
    });


req.end();
```

This return something like this in the response:

```
{"id":"123456","email":"bob\u0040gmail.com","name":"bobby bobski"}
```

Notice how the email doesn't have the '@' symbol instead it has \u0040. I do not want this, I would like the @ instead. I am not sure as I have not tested this, but I am thinking this will probably be occurring with all special characters. How do I make it so I get the actual character?

Comment: could you test this with curl?

Comment: `\u0040` and `@` symbol are synonyms in json

Comment: Btw, fix post title. As we could see https works properly, otherwise you would not get any response at all

Comment: are you using body parser??

Comment: @James111I am using it for many of my routes in express, but I am not using it for this request to Facebook.

Comment: You trying to confuse us.
JSON.stringify({ r: [ new Buffer("124"),  new Buffer("234") ]});
is evaluated to:
'{"r":[[49,50,52],[50,51,52]]}'
How did you get that string?

Comment: That is not what I get. I get a job string back. If I go console.log(JSON.stringify(fbResponse)); inside of nodejs on the end of the request I also get a Job string

Comment: I meant JSON not job

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. You need to parse the response and then stringify. It will then work.

```
console.log('This will now have the @ and not the unicode : ' + JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(fbResponse)) );
```

Comment: Are you gonna accept your own answer, or delete the question?

Comment: I will accept my answer as maybe it will help someone else in the future.

Comment: Would be great to know why the downvote on the answer and the question?

Comment: I agree. Perhaps a rename of question is in order, but down voting both may be a bit unnecessary